# Drupal-7 website is very very slow

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I am new to Drupal. My website is loading very slow. Can someone help me out with [this](http://samsweb.com.au/dt) website? I am trying different answers available on SO however no luck so far.

Comment: It's working normally for me. Did you fixed it somehow? Check is caching turned on.

Comment: I haven't fixed it yet. It is taking long time to load. is it loading faster on your browser?

Comment: It loads very fast on my side. Can you ping and tracert your server?

Comment: Some normal response...1 - 2 seconds...usual for Drupal.

Comment: If you clear the cache it's normal for first page loading after that to take more time.

Comment: @MilanG When I use www.samsweb.com.au/dt  it takes longer. But when i user www.samsweb.com.au/dt/ it loads faster . Am I doing mistake by not adding "/" after dt?

Comment: I think that when you are logged in you are not getting cached content. That's why anonymous user get faster response - they are getting content from drupal's cache.

Comment: @MilanG I use incognito window without logging in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find http://www.webpagetest.org/ is great for analysing where your website is waiting. With that information, you have the clues you need to delve deeper into the problem. Don't try setting up all sorts of complex mechanisms if, for example, your site is using huge image files.

Comment: I used suggested website to test my website and realised that when I use www.samsweb.com.au/dt  it is taking longer but with www.samsweb.com.au/dt/ it is faster. So I think my website is fine with the speed. I should test it once I upload on client's hosting. Please correct me if I am wrong. "dt" folder contains client's website

Answer (score 2):

You can check your site performance on [GtMatrix](http://gtmetrix.com) and Google [Developer tool](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights)

You should enable aggregate JS and minify HTML/CSS options.
There is a good module available [Advance aggregate](https://www.drupal.org/project/advagg) . You should use this module to improve site performance.

See [this answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/107311/eliminate-render-blocking-javascript-and-css-in-above-the-fold-content) for [Advance aggregate](https://www.drupal.org/project/advagg) module settings

Answer (score 1):

Its very difficult to know what modules and server configuration you are using with the website. But for improving the performance you can follow many steps which are as follows

1. Setting up Varnish or any equivalent reverse proxy caching for anonymous page caching.
2. using memcache.
3. gzip compression for js and css.
4. lazzy loading for images.
5. using views caching, block caching, entity caching with drupal.
6. Using APC (alternative php caching).
7. You can also use Boost module.
8. Using optimized image presets and using image sprites.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks, I will try those options. I found Varnish is a paid service. I am searching for free reverse proxy server.